# Consequences of disabling com.android.SystemUI

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, 5.1-lollipop, system-apps, disable-app

I have not been able to find the consecuences of disabling the SystemUI app (`com.android.systemui`) on Android Lollipop. The tablet is rooted so to disable it I just have to send the command `pm disable com.android.systemui` on ADB.

So far no app has crashed or have I seen any issues. The soft buttons and the quick settings and notifications bar dissapeared. Does someone know if there are any other consequences?

Answer (score 4):

[Is it safe to disable com.android.systemui?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29229474) from Stack overflow :

> If you completely remove SystemUI.apk from the system, your device will hang on start-up and never fully boot again. Tried it before. ;) Framework-res and the system have some dependencies on SystemUI.

Please also read the comments where OP did what you proposed and is warned that it could result in *soft bricking* the device.

Comment: Thanks for answering though this is not about the consequences of removing the SystemUI but about disabling. +1 though for the useful information on the link, although not conclusive.

Comment: System UI deals with the Notification drawer, settings, Popups etc. Also many apps call these components. And when they do, you'll have continuous loop of crashes.